# GridView shuffles views after updating

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

*Yes, I've seen other questions, but answers placed there didn't help me.*

I have images which my app loads from the Web placed in the `GridView`.
Here is the code of `getView` and `onScrollStateChanged`:

```java
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {

    switch(scrollState) {
        case SCROLL_STATE_FLING :
        case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL :
            downloader.stopAll();
            adapter.removeExecutor(productCategoriesExecutor);
        break;

        case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE :
            loadProductsChunk();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ProductView productView = (ProductView)view;

    if(productView == null) {
        productView = new ProductView(context, downloader);
        productView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(columnWidth, rowHeight));
    }

    JSONObject product = getItem(i);

    if(product != null) {
        try {
            Log.i("ololo", String.format("thm: %d ", i) + product.getString("thumbnail"));

            productView.setNewPrice(product.getInt("price"));
            productView.setOldPrice(product.getInt("oldPrice"));
            productView.showThumbnail(product.getString("thumbnail"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        productView.setNewPrice(0);
        productView.setOldPrice(0);
        productView.showThumbnail(null);
    }
    return productView;
}
```

And there is `GridView`:

```xml
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/productsGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/products_list_grid_spacing"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/products_list_grid_spacing"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
    />
```

As you see, `ProductView` receiving a link and then loads (or taking from cache) image.
Refreshing is performing where nor touching, neither scrolling now is active.

```java
public void displayRemoteImage(RemoteImage remoteImage) {
    if(this.remoteImage != null) {
        Log.i("ololo", this.remoteImage.getUrl() + remoteImage.getUrl());
    }

    if(this.remoteImage == null || !this.remoteImage.getUrl().equals(remoteImage.getUrl())) {
        this.remoteImage = remoteImage;
        this.remoteImage.setDelegate(this);
    }
}
```

[image: Okay]

But they blink if I scroll wherever and return back (with the OTHER PICS)!
Okay, it's not a big problem.
Let's load one more row

[image]

WHAT THE HELL??
And - yes - if I scroll wherever and return back there will be NEEDED pic (and there weren't reloading).

Okay, maybe we're losers and screwed in our downloading? Let's simply off refreshing pics:

[image]

Haha. Screw you guys, I'm going home.

Here is the updating log:

```
06-25 17:26:09.759: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.779: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/41/41230/41230thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.779: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.859: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.869: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.889: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.889: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.909: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40963/40963thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.919: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 1, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40748/40748thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.939: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40940/40940thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40748/40748thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.939: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 2, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40771/40771thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.999: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40934/40934thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40771/40771thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:09.999: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 3, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40790/40790thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.009: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40914/40914thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40790/40790thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.009: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 4, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40913/40913thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.029: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40913/40913thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40913/40913thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.029: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 5, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40914/40914thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.049: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40790/40790thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40914/40914thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.049: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 6, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40934/40934thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.069: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40771/40771thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40934/40934thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.069: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 7, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40940/40940thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.089: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40748/40748thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40940/40940thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.099: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 8, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/40/40963/40963thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.159: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/40/40963/40963thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.330: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.340: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.340: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.390: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.390: INFO/ololo(6613): viewId: 0, should show the link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
06-25 17:26:10.410: INFO/ololo(6613): original link: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg; should show: http://mysite//img/products/3/3031/3031thm.jpg
```

### Update

This is happening on the HTC Explorer (2.3.3) and HTC Nexus One (2.3.6) but not happening on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (3.2).

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_twolistitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from inner realization of `BaseAdapter`. It seems it stores views in stack or something like that so after the screen updating it places the views in the reverse order. The solution is to speed up data refreshing as much as possible. And remember that you shouldn't use async data refreshing: it will cause blinking.

Answer (score 0):

use the ViewHolder pattern.
and an ImageManager that downloads and caches .